# Arabic text insertion through Wix in SQL Script

Tags: sql-server, character-encoding, wix, right-to-left, wix3.8

**I have the Arabic text in the insert statement its insert ????? or some wired characters through WIX SQL Script**

```
<sql:SqlScript Id='Insertion1' BinaryKey='Insertion' Sequence='3'  ExecuteOnInstall='yes' ContinueOnError='yes' />
```

this is the command i have for the insertion like

```
delimiter$$
INSERT INTO
[dbo].[Location]([Id],[LocationDesc],[LocationDesc_AR],[LocationTypeID],[FullLocationDesc_AR],[CreateDate],[UpdatedDate],[CreatedBy])
VALUES(566,'Al Souq JTC',N'السوق','1',N'تقاطع السوق','4/21/2014 12:42:51
PM','4/21/2014 12:43:24 PM','')$$
delimiter $$
```

when i run the scripts its working fine but through WIX TOOL SET its not insert properly.

Comment: mysql or sql-server? Please tag the actual DBMS (vendor and version).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code of your query I thought: Oh sure! The leading `N` in front of your arabic literals is missing. At least I cannot see it in my browser.

I copied your code to my SQL window and - magic! - the leading `N` is there...

Jumping with arrow keys through your text shows clearly, that this actual string is implicitly defined as RTL (*right-to-left*), you cannot even mark it by moving the mouse over it...

These are two examples working in SQL Server

```
SELECT N'السوق'
SELECT N'تقاطع السوق'
```

Without the `N` you get question marks

```
SELECT 'السوق'
SELECT 'تقاطع السوق'
```

My assumption: Your tool cannot deal with RTL-characters. Even the Chrome-Browser here on SO can't... The leading N is somehow swallowed...

#### UPDATE Test the effect of additional linebreaks

Your code, just copy and paste. **The leading `N` is there but invisible!!**

```
INSERT INTO
[dbo].[Location]([Id],[LocationDesc],[LocationDesc_AR],[LocationTypeID],[FullLocationDesc_AR],[CreateDate],[UpdatedDate],[CreatedBy])
VALUES(566,'Al Souq JTC',N'السوق','1',N'تقاطع السوق','4/21/2014 12:42:51
PM','4/21/2014 12:43:24 PM','')
```

Line breaks before the comma

```
INSERT INTO
[dbo].[Location]([Id],[LocationDesc],[LocationDesc_AR],[LocationTypeID],[FullLocationDesc_AR],[CreateDate],[UpdatedDate],[CreatedBy])
VALUES
(566
 ,'Al Souq JTC'
 ,N'السوق'
 ,'1'
 ,N'تقاطع السوق'
 ,'4/21/2014 12:42:51 PM'
 ,'4/21/2014 12:43:24 PM','')
```

At least my browser **does** show the leading `N` if this is not bound together without any blank or linebreak... Give it a try...

#### Update 2

My working example from above in one line works:

```
SELECT N'السوق',N'تقاطع السوق'
```

But now try to place non-RTL values between them (have to put it non-arabic, to show what I mean):

```
SELECT N'arabic',123,N'arabic'
```

My browser muddles this up completely, your tool too probably...

Comment: Need to check with wixtool set that it support the arabic in Inseration  script or not .

Comment: No, still looking the answer.